# How to pass constant value to AWS Step Function using Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

I want to pass some payload to Step Function triggered by Cloudwatch rule. After passing payload, who can I receive it in Step Function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass a payload to the step function you should pass in a constant, this will be a fixed JSON string that gets passed during every trigger.

[image]

From the image above you can see the ability to specify a JSON string, this will replace any of the previous input that would have been passed into the step function (the event JSON).

Comment: How can I access it in Step Function ?

Comment: In step function, I'm spinning up a cluster first and after that I'm submitting a Spark job in it. Actually I want to pass that Input to the Spark Job which is at State 2.

Comment: This would pass in as input to the first step in the step function, more information about inputs and outputs of step functions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-input-output-filtering.html :)